# R: Generate a table of win/loss records against specific players

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="p1 p2 outcome
jon joe 1-0
jon james 0-1
james ken 1-0
ken jon 1-0", header=T)
```

I'm trying to use dplyr to output a summary table of some specific player's (e.g. jon's) statistics against every other player in the dataframe.  So, the output should be:

```
joe: 1-0
james: 1-0
ken: 0-1
```

I want to use 'group_by' to work with a corpus of joe games, but don't know how to implement conditional group_by's (e.g. group_by joe if p1 or p2 == joe).  I could mutate to create a dummy column that is equal to 1 if either of those conditions are true, and group_by that, but was hoping there was a more parsimonious strategy.  And then, the only way I can see of counting a 'win' for Joe is to use an ifelse statement whereby if p1 == Joe and outcome == 1-0 or p2 == Joe and outcome == 0-1, then count that as a win for Joe.  However, not sure how to do these if statements within dplyr piping.

Comment: I think it should be `james 0-1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be a `dplyr` solution that allows for multiple games between jon and the other players (not just one game). It basically filters all games that jon was part of and extracts the opponent via `mutate` and `ifelse`. It then summarizes the number of wins and losses after grouping by opponent. In the end I paste the overall result for each opponent and only select this pasted column:

```
dat %>% mutate(p1 = as.character(p1), p2 = as.character(p2)) %>% 
  filter((p1 == "jon")|(p2 == "jon")) %>%
  mutate(opponent= ifelse(p1 == "jon",p2,p1)) %>% 
  group_by(opponent) %>%
  summarize(Wins = sum((outcome == "1-0" & p1 == "jon") | 
                       (outcome == "0-1" & p2 == "jon")) ,
            Losses = n() - Wins) %>%
  mutate(Outcome = paste(opponent, ": ",Wins, "-", Losses)) %>%
  select(Outcome)
```

I had to add the `as.character` mutate to properly return the opponents in the `ifelse`. Otherwise the variables `p1` and `p2` would still be factor and the numbers would be returned instead of the labels (i.e. names of the players).

Comment: Wow, this is really incredible -- and so straightforward now that I see it.  I liked this line `mutate(opponent= ifelse(p1 == "jon",p2,p1))` --- really clever

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative `tidyverse` solution:

```
# example data
dat <- read.table(text="
p1 p2 outcome
jon joe 1-0
jon james 0-1
james ken 1-0
ken jon 1-0", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(tidyverse)

# reshape your dataset
dat2 = dat %>%
  mutate(game_id = row_number()) %>%  # add game id
  unite(p, p1, p2, sep="-") %>%       # combine player names
  separate_rows(p, outcome)           # separate rows using name and scores

# get summary stats for jon
dat2 %>%
  group_by(game_id) %>%               # for each game id
  filter("jon" %in% p) %>%            # keep games that jon played
  summarise(pl = p[p != "jon"],       # get the name of the other player
            outcome = paste0(outcome[p=="jon"], "-", outcome[p!="jon"]))  # combine the scores (jon vs. other)

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   game_id pl    outcome
#     <int> <chr> <chr>  
# 1       1 joe   1-0    
# 2       2 james 0-1    
# 3       4 ken   0-1
```

Assuming you can reshape you original dataset once, in beginning, you can create a function using the second part:

```
GetSummaryStats = function(x) {
  dat2 %>%
    group_by(game_id) %>%              
    filter(x %in% p) %>%            
    summarise(pl = p[p != x],       
              outcome = paste0(outcome[p==x], "-", outcome[p!=x])) }
```

and call it like this:

```
GetSummaryStats("jon")
```

for any player you like.

Comment: Wow! This is also really instructive.  Thanks so much

Comment: Again, great answer.  I'm re-reading it-- could you explain how this line works: `(pl = p[p != "jon"]` . I'm confused as to where pl is coming from and how you're indexing p like that

Comment: Give me the player, when player is not Jon.